# Limit of 4Kbytes when using print in AWK?

Tags: printing, awk, wildcard

I'm trying to replace a a blank line in a set of text files (*.txt) for a "--" if the previous line matchs a pattern. My code is

```
awk 'BEGIN{$headerfound=0} { if (/pattern/) {print> FILENAME ; $headerfound=1} else { if((/^\s*$/) && ($headerfound == 1)) { $headerfound=0; print "--" > FILENAME } else {print > FILENAME} } }' *.txt
```

But for some reason, output is limited to 4kbytes files (if the file is larger, it gets clipped). Do you know where is the limitation?

Thanks,
Ariel

Comment: Writing to a file while you're reading it is a recipe for disaster. Generally you'd write to a temp file, and move that temp file to the "real" file after you've finished processing the file.

Comment: Don't use `$` for awk variables. `$` is an operator for getting the *value* of the field named by the variable (or expression)

Comment: Just ellaborating on Glen's answer,.. I needed to replace a blank line just afterwars a pattern, so i came up with the modified code below, for sure not nearly as elegant as the responses but it works suffix=".$$.tmp" 

awk -v suf="$suffix" '
    FNR == 1 {outfile = FILENAME suf}
    {   
    if (/pattern/) 
     {headerfound = 1}
    else if (headerfound && /^[[:blank:]]*$/)  
     {$1 = "--"; headerfound=0}
    else 
     {headerfound=0}
    } 
    { print > outfile }
' *.txt

for f in *.txt; do
    mv "${f}${suffix}" "$f"
done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get away with:

```
suffix=".$$.tmp" '

awk -v suf="$suffix" '
    FNR == 1 {outfile = FILENAME suf}
    /pattern/ {headerfound = 1}
    headerfound && /^[[:blank:]]*$/ {$1 = "--"}
    { print > outfile }
' *.txt

for f in *.txt; do
    echo mv "${f}$suffix" "$f"
done
```

Remove the `echo` from the for loop if you're satisfied it's working.

---

Missed the "just after" requirement (using Ed's use of `NF` to find a blank line):

```
awk -v suf="$suffix" '
    FNR == 1 {outfile = FILENAME suf}
    /pattern/ {lineno = FNR}
    FNR == lineno+1 && NF == 0 {$0 = "--"}
    { print > outfile }
' *.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn! worked perfectly. Just added a braket in the mv:mv "${f}${suffix}" "$f"

Answer (score 3):

See @glennjackman's comments for problems in your script.

Since you are using GNU awk (you used `\s` which is gawk-specific) you can use inplace-editing and write your script as (spread out with white space to improve readability):

```
awk -i inplace '{
    if (/pattern/) {
        print
        headerfound=1
    } else {
        if((/^\s*$/) && (headerfound == 1)) {
            headerfound=0
            print "--"
        } else {
            print
        }
    }
}' *.txt
```

but you can do the same thing much more concisely (and awk-ishly) as:

```
awk -i inplace '
    /pattern/ { headerfound=1 }
    headerfound && !NF { $0="--"; headerfound=0 }
1' *.txt
```

If you don't have inplace editing then do it this way:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    awk '
        /pattern/ { headerfound=1 }
        headerfound && !NF { $0="--"; headerfound=0 }
    1' "$file" > tmp$$ &&
    mv tmp$$ "$file"
done
```

Comment: Marked Glenn's solution because i do not have 4.1 in my ubuntu machine

Comment: That's fine but if you have a problem creating the tmp file Glenn's solution will remove your original file which may not be desirable. I updated my answer with a non-gawk solution that won't do that.